# Php syntax for echoing multiple classes with a space between them

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax

I'm am working on a Wordpress custom template and I'm filtering post by their classes.
Since Wordpress displays a LOT of unnecessary classes when I put `<?php post_class(); ?>` in a page, 
( here is what it gives me `class="post-54 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-3d category-web"` )
 I'm trying to simplify that by echoing only the categories that relate to the post.

**EDIT:** 
This is what calls the post in my page `<?php query_posts( 'showposts=99' ); ?>`

Then this piece of code

```
<li class="<?php if ( in_category('category-3d')) { echo "3d"; }
        if ( in_category('category-animation')) { echo "animation"; }
        if ( in_category('category-motion')) { echo "motion"; }
        if ( in_category('category-shortfilm')) { echo "shortfilm"; }?>"></li>
```

give me this `<li class="motion"></li>` if my post is in the "motion" category.

The problem is that **if my post is in several categories, only the first is echoed**... How can I tell WP to echo ALL the names of the categories my post is affected to, while adding a space between them?

Since I am a beginner in php syntax, I'm still learning how to get such a simple thing working in a clean and effective way (i.e. without writing 16 lines of code !)...
Can someone help me on this one?

**SECOND EDIT:**
Ok I'm still trying to figure out why, but today, my piece of code (above) is working and echoes all my listed classes, but without space between them... So to make my classes work, I'm adding a space at the end of the echo part like this `{ echo "3d "; }`. But I feel like it's a dirty way to make things work... 
**How to add a space between each class tag in the proper way?**  I'm aiming for something like this `foreach $categories as $cat { echo $cat . " "; }` but where $categories and $cat would refer to each "if" statement.

Comment: `3d` isn't a valid class name. Prefix your classes with something like `category-`.

Comment: Thx, I used to have that, here I just copied my draft, that's edited!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with WP but if you get your categories with some function like `get_categories()` then you can use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to make a string from all categories.

```
<?php $categories = get_categories(); ?>
<?php $categories = implode(' ', $categories); ?>
<li class="<?php echo $categories; ?>">...</li>
```

Could you provide what is returning `get_categories()`?

### EDIT:

```
function get_class_attr() {
    $classes = get_post_class(); 
    $classes = substr($classes, 7, -1);

    $arr = array();
    $arr = explode(' ', $classes);
    $classes = 'class="';

    foreach($arr as $class_name) { 
        if(strpos($class_name, 'category-') !== false) {
            $classes .= substr($class_name, 9).' ';
        }
    }

    $classes = substr_replace($classes, '"', -1, 1);
    echo $classes;
}

get_class_attr(); // output: class="3d web"
```

Also note that `3d` is not a valid class name, you can use something like `movie3d` or `film3d`.

Alternative way is to create your class value a little bit earlier and then `echo` it:

```
<?php
$classes = array();
if ( in_category('category-3d'))        { $classes[] = "3d"; }
if ( in_category('category-animation')) { $classes[] = "animation"; }
if ( in_category('category-motion'))    { $classes[] = "motion"; }
if ( in_category('category-shortfilm')) { $classes[] = "shortfilm";}

if(count($classes)) {
    $classes = implode(' ', $classes);
} else {
    $classes = '';
}
?>

<li class="<?php $classes ?>"></li>
```

Comment: Thank you guys but all your codes returned me errors. Maybe I did somthing wrong... And I wish I could stick as much as possible with what I've already written (or at least keep the logic of it) and just add the condition that could echo the rest of my classes. That way I can control what WP displays and understand it since I'm learning at the same time. Is there something wrong with the part I've written? (cc @feeela )

Comment: Ok, how did you get the categories for a specific post? As I said I'm not familiar with WP but there should be a function like `get_categories()` or something like that to get an array with the categories.

Comment: When I create a post, I just add a category name and then it's stored somewhere. When I call `<?php post_class(); ?>` in my `li`, it echoes this `class="post-54 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-3d category-web"` which is waaay too much. So with my little piece of code, I try to echo only the 2 or 3 items I need. Not sure I'm very clear... :)

Comment: So your own categories are actually coming like `category-xyz`? In this case they are only `3d` and `web`, right?

Comment: yes they are coming like this category-xyz, but when I use my piece of code they are turned into xyz. The problem is that sometimes a post can be in "xyz" AND let's say "abc", and in this case, only "xyz" appears. I'm trying to get "abc" too.

Comment: I even tried playing with an array but I don't what to write after... `<?php if ( in_category( array( '3d', 'animation', 'motion', 'shortfilm', 'web', /*etc*/ ) )) { echo  '/*what to put here*/ '; } ?>`

Comment: Ouch, you totally confused me. Could you edit your first post and paste what `post_class()` is returning exactly as is.

Comment: Done. Yeah sorry, it's hard to explain when you don't master the vocabulary... :)

Comment: I edited my answer. Maybe it will be necessery to pass an ID to the function, like on `<?php query_posts( 'showposts=99' ); ?>` on your code.

Comment: I tried to place it in my page but only got errors... What do you mean by passing an ID to the function?

Comment: Ok I've seen your edit, but in `<?php query_posts( 'showposts=99' ); ?>`, 99 is not an ID but the number of post to display on the page. For example I can change it to -1 to display ALL the posts. Maybe I should start a new thread and try to be more clear don't you think? :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest instead you use [this function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) from the Wordpress API - something you should read a lot of.

Something like this should work:

```
<?php $categories = get_categories(); ?>
<li class="<?php foreach ($categories as $cat) {
    echo $cat . " ";
 }?>"> -- Your li text --
</li>
```

Comment: thx I'm already a lot into the codex but I'm trying to improve my skills in php. Was there something wrong with the part I've written? Your code returns me an error.

Comment: Yeah I paste it right after `<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>` and it return me `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting '(' in C:\Program Files (x86)\...\The address of my template\home.php on line 64` and line 64 is that one `<li class="<?php foreach $categories as $cat { echo $cat . " "; }?>">`

Answer (score 0):

As of the code you've posted, it should add all the categories if the product is in all the four specified ones. You could add the space between the quotes after each `echo`, e.g.: `echo ' motion'`.

I would use another approach, adding really all categories, without the need to check them by name:

```
<li class="<?php echo implode( ' ', get_categories() ); ?>"> … </li>
```

See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories on how to filter the output of the function `get_categories()`.